# Using AFNetwork to load a collectionView from Instagram, but seems to blow right by my code, leaving me with no images

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, instagram

I can retrieve what I need using the Instagram API, but (what I understand) is since AFNetworking operates asynchronous, the code jumps right into my CollectionView methods but yet my AFNetworking call is still at work, the CollectionView cells never load. There is no array ready. Used [operation waitUntilFinished]; but does not seem to do anything.

Code here, thanks!

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = @"https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snow/media/recent?access_token=836379.f59def8.fd07b9ba8ea440188dc56d2763bbf6c2";

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
    [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

                                                        imageArray = [[[[JSON valueForKey:@"data"]valueForKey:@"images"]valueForKey:@"low_resolution"]valueForKey:@"url"];




                                                        for (id item in imageArray) {


                                                            [images addObject:item];

                                                        }



                                                    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){
                                                        // NSLog(@"There was a problem: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                                    }];

    [operation start];
    [operation waitUntilFinished];  // DOES NOT STOP AND WAIT

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

/* RETURNS ARRAY COUNT OF ZER0 HERE, BUT I AM EXPECTING A VALID ARRAY OF URLS!

   return  [imageArray count];
}

- (CollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellZero" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;

}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple. In your success callback block, just call

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

This ensures that the collection view reload after the AFNetworking library successfully fetches the data from Instagram API. Actually, what I would do is to refactor the callback function in another method called "reloadCollectionViewWithImages:(NSArray *)imageArray":

```
- (void)reloadCollectionViewWithImages:(NSArray *)imageArray {
    for (id item in imageArray) {
        [images addObject:item];
    }
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

and call this method inside the success callback.

Comment if you have any other question :)

Comment: I ended up using this format for reload: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  
        [self.collectionView reloadData];  
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Reload the collection view data in the success block of your network request, after adding all the images to the imageArray: [UICollectionView reloadData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/reloadData)

Also have a look at [valueForKeypath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/valueForKeyPath%3a), that can help you get rid of those nested valueForKey calls.

Answer (score 0):

Adding [self.collectionView reloadData]; works great. thanks Both answers came in at the same time. But only could check one. Thanks to both!